# Mediawiki: File upload error

Tags: mediawiki

When tried to upload files of **12.7MB(djvu)** and **7MB(mp4)** **mediawiki** showed an error saying:

```
    Internal error
    [89512f99] 2014-10-21 06:29:26: Fatal exception of type UploadStashFileException
```

**Maximum file size: 20 MB (a file on your computer)

Permitted file types: png, gif, jpg, jpeg, mp4, djvu, mp3, pdf.**

Comment: Are there any details besides the exception type?

Answer (score 0):

There are some known bugs with the upload stash, please upgrade to [MediaWiki 1.24](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki_1.24) (just released) which includes some fixes, hopefully solving the error for you too.

The next thing you can do, given your files are so small, is to visit Special:Preferences on your wiki and disable "chunked uploading". You'll then use the standard upload, which is less powerful but usually less fragile.

If that fails as well, probably the issue is deeper, e.g. you might have misconfigured the upload directory. Better double check your uploads configuration and enable debugging (see [Manual:Debug](https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Debug)) to have more details on your error. If that doesn't help, please file a bug at http://phabricator.wikimedia.org.